# Hover Share Button Over Every Image

Tags: html, css

I am using an embedded quiz platform, see https://output.jsbin.com/pabopusulo.

I want to make every image hover a "Share button" centered in the middle.

**Facebook share code:**

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="box_count"></div>
```

I tried doing this using CSS by calling the div to `display:block;` but it did not work. I am not sure if this is even possible. Please keep in mind, I am new to coding.

Thanks all.

UPDATE:
**embedded script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.playbuzz.com/widget/feed.js"></script>
<div class="pb_feed" data-embed-by="6c7dc1a3-ea2c-490e-8b3f-8526cdf5bcb4" data-game="/drishtib10/what-is-your-personality-type-according-to-your-perception" data-recommend="false" data-game-info="false" data-comments="false" data-shares="false" ></div>
```

Comment: I updated it! @ketan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

**Note:** You can't see the result here because of security reason, so I created a [bin](http://output.jsbin.com/furefuk) for this.

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  opacity:0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.fb-share-button.fb_iframe_widget {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:1;
  transition:all .3s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover .fb-share-button.fb_iframe_widget,
.wrapper:hover:before {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=850697865046018";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/03/06/16/51/balance-1240737__180.jpg" />
  <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although, I want it to hover on these images.... Check out this Bin: https://output.jsbin.com/pabopusulo

Comment: I can't see the images in this bin.

Comment: I have updated the question and inserted a script for you to see. 

The code there is an embedded quiz game which contains the images. You can find it by running it on the bin

Comment: So how do you want to insert the `share` button? using javascript?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Javascript that much but if it's going to work then I'm all for it.